# How can I run tests on React components that use jQuery?

Tags: reactjs, mocha.js, chai

I have a React component that uses a jQuery selector to match the height of all components in the componentDidMount():

```
$('.js-matchHeight').matchHeight();
```

Works fine when running Servers like webpack, but when I write my specs (Mocha and Chai), it complains:

> ReferenceError: $ is not defined

How can I add jQuery to my tests?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried adding browser-env to your tests ?

```
import browserEnv from 'browser-env';
browserEnv();
```

I had similar issue with unit test done with AVA and I think that resolved the issue. Not sure but I think I also imported jQuery and/or Cheerio.

**EDIT:**

Well the workaround I have is to test against jQuery in your components like:

```
if (typeof jQuery !== 'undefined') {
    $('.js-matchHeight').matchHeight();
}
```

or if you have jQuery in a module that you import you can export different component versions like:

```
module.exports = (typeof jQuery !== 'undefined')
    ? browser(jQuery)
    : nonBrowser();
```

Non of this is perfect but if you want perfect you should keep jQuery away from your jsx I think :)

Comment: Thanks @marcinrek!  I tried but didn't work.  I think the browserEnv doesn't add jQuery.  I also can't import jQuery into my test.jsx since the component being tested needs jQuery, not the test.

Comment: browserEnv does not add jQuery but should enable you to add it. I assume you are not putting jQuery in your bundle this is why it is undefined. If you add it to your component without browserEnv it will not work as well as jQuery required window, document etc ... That is why I suggested adding it - sorry for not making it more clear. I know I have it working but I don't have access to that repo from home so if no one answers untill tomorrow I will take another look :)

Comment: and if you are not testing against something that is done by jQuery you can always use a dirty workaround like if (typeof(jQuery) !== 'undefined') { $('.js-matchHeight').matchHeight(); }